# Creating View in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to create a view on my database but I keep getting ORA-00934:

> group function is not allowed here error

Any help?

Here is my code:

```
CREATE VIEW MY_PRODUCTS_CE2_SELECT_MBILI
AS SELECT PROD_NAME,PROD_CATEGORY,PROD_SUBCATEGORY 
FROM MY_PRODUCTS_CE2
WHERE PROD_LIST_PRICE > AVG(PROD_LIST_PRICE)    
WITH CHECK OPTION CONSTRAINT MyProductsCE2SelectMbili_Cnst;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't put aggregate function in `WHERE` clause.

Change your query to this:

```
CREATE VIEW MY_PRODUCTS_CE2_SELECT_MBILI 
AS SELECT PROD_NAME,PROD_CATEGORY,PROD_SUBCATEGORY 
FROM MY_PRODUCTS_CE2 WHERE PROD_LIST_PRICE > (SELECT AVG(PROD_LIST_PRICE) FROM MY_PRODUCTS_CE2)
WITH CHECK OPTION CONSTRAINT MyProductsCE2SelectMbili_Cnst;
```

More : [Oracle/PLSQL: ORA-00934 Error](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/errors/ora00934.php)

Comment: Sorry for the really late response but this worked. Thank you.